# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, io

I am using a 3rd party server and  I am trying to upload an image to the server from my web form which I made in c# mvc.It works fine om my localhost and when I published it it give me an error

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\InetPub\vhosts\abc.com\httpdocs\Images\Sections\Developer\ClientLogo\circle-small-empty.18x18.png' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper.SaveAs(String filename) at ab.CorporateSite.Controllers.DeveloperController.ImagePath(HttpPostedFileBase imgfile).
```

Throgh filezilla I have checked the rights on the particualr folder o server where i want to save images (ClientLogo folder), acc. to that it has full rights and on my local system also I gave full rights to network service and everyone.

I am struggling with this problem since yesterday and nothing is working out.Please suggest me what should I do??

Answer (score 3):

You need to grant rights to the folder for the [IIS application pool identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) under which your application is running.

The virtual user that needs the rights is typically `IIS AppPool\AppPoolNameGoesHere`.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio development server on my localhost so I don;t have IIS on my comp. and as I amusing 3rd party server so I dont have access to t. So i'll do tht

Comment: Thanks I have talked to 3rd party server person and they gave rights on my website.Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the selected answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: this anwser is gold

Answer (score 1):

**Add permissions to users/groups:**
In IIS Server go to your site -> Edit Permissions of folder -> Go to *Security* tab and grant permissions to appropriate users or groups.